# What happens if I pass a non-null terminated buffer as the first argument to strstr?

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

As I understand, the function `char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);` searches for the null terminated string s2 in the null terminated string s1.

Let's say, I pass a null terminated string s2, but the buffer passed as s1 is not null terminated, what will happen in such a case if the string s2 is not present in s1? The function strstr will keep searching for s2 beginning from the start address of s1, till it finds some '\0'. But, let's say it doesn't find a `'\0'` at all? Will it access some protected or prohibited memory area and crash?

I know this is an undefined behavior, but based on your experiences, what could be the problem?

Comment: As you say, the behavior is undefined. And as you say, it could easily access some protected or prohibited memory area and crash.

The problem is that your code needs to be corrected so it doesn't pass an unterminated buffer to `strstr`. Apart from that, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: process crash since you're bound to run out of the allocated memory bounds.

Comment: @JanDvorak unless a `'\0'` is encountered before the end of accessible memory.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart actually, under the right circumstances, it's quite likely the string will be found: if both arguments are on the stack and in the correct order.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Yes. I agree. : ) I believe in the points written by me, but one of my colleagues is of the opinion that it can still work and no major problem will occur, as there is a good probability of it encountering some other '\0' or the sub-string.. So, we decided to get the experts opinion. That's the point. : )

Comment: @JanDvorak, "actually, under the right circumstances, it's quite likely the string will be found" - But, it is still too risky to code it in this way. right?

Comment: @Jay: It's very foolish to depend on what will *probably* happen. Unless you're doing statistics, probabilities (other than 0 or 1) should not be relevant to your program's behavior. If you're passing non-null-terminated arrays to `strstr()`, you need to fix your code so it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know this is an undefined behavior

And here ends your question. Because it is UB, nobody can tell you what **will** happen for sure. Yes, it may cause an access violation and dump core. It may accidentally encounter a 0 somewhere in the memory and stop there. It may find the substring as well (small chance). Or it may cause demons to fly out of your nose.

Comment: "Or it may cause demons to fly out of your nose" - LOL! : )

Comment: @Jay actually, the term "nasal demons" dates back to 1992 at least.